# Can a holocron be hacked and its data extracted by a droid?

Tags: star-wars-force-and-destiny, hacking

As a player is trying it for the first time. Is it even possible that a holocron can be hacked by a droid with his interface and the data extracted?

Or is it impossible / too difficult?

Answer (score 2):

Holocrons traditionally require use of the Force to activate, so that's a hurdle for a droid in and of itself. Once a holocron is opened it can be interacted with by non-force-weilding characters, but still only through its "Guardian" interface. See the [Wookiepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Holocron/Legends) page for more details, it's rather similar for both Legends and the new cannon.

Ultimately when dealing with Star Wars technology I personally rely on what feels in tune with the source material; in this case I don't really see it.

All that being said, roleplaying is about creating new stories together. If this kind of thing is cool and would fuel interesting stories then by all means hand-wave it in. The core crystal could be extracted by a force user, then decoded. This could be done by either new tech or maybe very old tech.